# Captured UIView image is blurry on full screen display

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to capture the 2/3 of the screen with same proportions of the main screen. As a result I get a blurry image when I capture the screen and display it full screen in the same device. How to capture the smaller part and display fullscreen without quality loss?

```
//Get image of the view 
- (UIImage *)getScreenshot {
    CGRect rect = [_shareView bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [_shareView.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *capturedScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return capturedScreen;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From apple documentation

```
func UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_ size: CGSize, 
                                          _ opaque: Bool, 
                                          _ scale: CGFloat)
```

## scale

The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

so you set scale to zero you have to set to 3 or 2

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 2.0)
```

Comment: Share image for result you have please

Comment: its same image for all 0.0, 2.0 and 3.0

Comment: Yes send image for me with result I need to see it

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are not setting the scale of your layer to render.

```
layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Leaving it as the default (1) will give you blurry or pixelated captures on retina devices.

Comment: I added _shareView.layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale; but it didn't help.